# Faster way to Vlookup and return multiple results?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have looked for over a day here in Stackoverflow and cannot find an answer to what I am trying to do.
All I need is a vba code that Vlookups and return the multiple results,

Eg; the lookup value is in sheet1 A1, data is in sheet2 columns A1:B40000, match the values in sheet2 A1:A40000 and returns the values from Sheet2 column B1:B40000.

Note:Its possible to find upto 5000 matches in sheet2 A1:A40000.

I have tried several ways to do this, such as Array formula (VERY SLOW), UDF (SLOW), VBA-AutoFilter(SLOW).
Is there any way to do this quickly?

Can anyone help?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of "SLOW"?  (I wouldn't have thought that an `AutoFilter` would have been terribly slow.)  Maybe post your code that you tried using the `AutoFilter` approach and we might be able to work out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @YowE3K
It takes around 30..40 seconds to load the results.

Comment: I would have proposed AutoFilter, too. So now I'm curious to see your code with it ...

Comment: @YowE3K

Checkout Tigeravatar's answer

Comment: Now I'm curious to know which code is faster...

Comment: 30 to 40 seconds for a simple `AutoFilter` is waaaay too long.  Even when I filter a million rows with about 200 columns using several criteria it doesn't take that long - more like 3 or 4 seconds at the most.  (But perhaps I just doze off while it is running and wake up again once it is finished?  That wouldn't surprise me these days.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code tested with 40,000 entries, and this completes basically instantly:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vLoookupVal As Variant
    Dim vValues As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim lResultCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lIndex As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = Me                    'This is the sheet that contains the lookup value
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")   'This is the sheet that contains the table of values

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Columns("B").ClearContents   'Clear previous results
        vLoookupVal = Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("A1")).Value
        lResultCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Columns("A"), Target.Value)
        If lResultCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No matches found for [" & vLoookupVal & "]", , "No Matches"
        Else
            ReDim aResults(1 To lResultCount, 1 To 1)
            lIndex = 0
            vValues = ws2.Range("A1:B" & ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
            For i = LBound(vValues, 1) To UBound(vValues, 1)
                If vValues(i, 1) = vLoookupVal Then
                    lIndex = lIndex + 1
                    aResults(lIndex, 1) = vValues(i, 2)
                End If
            Next i
            ws1.Range("B1").Resize(lResultCount).Value = aResults
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch mate!! It Works like a charm!

Comment: Hello there,
Is it possible to retrieve data from Sheet2 Column C as well?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your AutoFilter code wasn't like this one?

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim lookUpVal As Variant

    lookUpVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")  
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, lookUpVal) = 0 Then Exit Sub
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:= lookUpVal
            .Resize(,2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode= False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table would speed things up and you can use the filter as the search function?